# LIVEWARE error Unable to find component: [navigation-menu]

Tags: laravel, components, laravel-10, laravel-jetstream

I am installed for the first time jetstream liveware on laravel 10.28 with node.js version 20.7.0 but when I boot the server and test the dashboard I get this error:

> Livewire\Exceptions  \ComponentNotFoundException Unable to find component: [navigation-menu]

[image: Error navigation-menu]

In some tutorials, I was suggested to change the file "resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php" @livewire('navigation-menu') to @livewire('navigation-staff') but the error persists. Any advice or someone gave you the same problem and you were able to solve it?